# LaTeX expansion of number into ordinal suffix

Tags: expansion, write

For a project I am working on I want to automatically 'calculate' the ordinal suffix for numbers. I need to calculate ordinals for various numbers, and later also write them to an external file (the project itself is a fully automated agenda). However, calculating ordinals for different numbers results in errors. I approach this in the following manner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\meetingNumbersconly{}
\newcommand\lastMeetingNumbersconly{}

%% Determine superscript of given raw number
\newcommand\getSuperscript[1]{%
    \ifnum\lasttwo>10\ifnum\lasttwo<14 th\fi\else
        \ifnum\lastone>3 th\else%
        \ifnum\lastone=0 th\else%
        \ifnum\lastone=3 rd\else%
        \ifnum\lastone=2 nd\else st%
        \fi\fi\fi\fi%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand\meetingNumberDefault[1]{
    \StrRight{#1}{2}[\lasttwo]%
    \StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastone]%
    \renewcommand\meetingNumbersconly{\getSuperscript{#1}}
}

\newcommand\meetingNumberLast[1]{
    \StrRight{#1}{2}[\lasttwo]%
    \StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastone]%    
    \renewcommand\lastMeetingNumbersconly{\getSuperscript{#1}}
}

\meetingNumberDefault{2}
\meetingNumberLast{1}

% \newwrite\general
% \openout\general=information.txt
% \write\general{\lastMeetingNumbersc}
% \closeout\general

\begin{document}
    2\textsuperscript{\meetingNumbersconly} \& 1\textsuperscript{\lastMeetingNumbersconly}
\end{document}
```

The problem here is that the intended results should be `2nd & 1st`. The output is `2st & 1st`, however. I think I understand why this happens: `\@@meetingNumbersconly` and `\@@lastMeetingNumbersconly` hold the same value, but this is not the intention.

The solution would be as easy as moving the following bit of code within the `\@getSuperscript` command.

```
\StrRight{#1}{2}[\@lasttwo]%
\StrRight{#1}{1}[\@lastone]%
```

However, this is not possible as later in the code, I try to write the superscript to an external file using `\write\general{<li>\@@lastMeetingNumbersc</li>}`. By trying to do so, other errors arise.

Another solution would be to make two commands for `\@getSuperscript`, one for each ordinal. Since I want to keep the code as clean as possible, I also rather not do this.

I have been fiddling around with expansion for a few hours but I have not really found a way to achieve my goal: having the intended output `2nd & 1st` while also being able to write the intended results to a file. Does anybody have any suggestions besides duplicated code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a short working example of code that demonstrates the issue, rather than just a non-compilable code snippet.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have added a MWE, please let me know if you need anything more :)

Comment: Why don't you `\usepackage[super]{nth}` then `\nth{2} \& \nth{1}`?

Comment: beware `\ifnum\lasttwo>10\ifnum...` will force the second `\fnum` test to be executed before the first, as it will be looking for further digits to follow 10 (you want a space after `10`)

Comment: also a `%` here does nothing `\else%` but you have missing `%` after `{` and `}` in several lines which will cause spurious white space in output.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I consider looking into that, I will report back if this works out

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik using the package solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @G.deMan Added an answer with a note on why your code doesn't work and the alternative

Comment: This functionality is also available in [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool).

Comment: `\usepackage{fmtcount}` and then `\ordinalnum{2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your commands is that after doing `\meetingNumberDefault{1}`, you will have `\lasttwo` be `2` and `\lastone` be `2`, and `\meetingNumbersconly` will be `\getSuperscript{2}`, and *not* `st` (use `\show\meetingNumbersconly` to see).  Then, you do `\meetingNumberLast{1}` which changes `\lasttwo` and `\lastone` again to `1`.  Then when you use `\meetingNumbersconly` it will get the suffix for the last value of `\lasttwo` and `\lastone`, thus you get `st` in both cases (just try changing the order of `\meetingNumberDefault{2}` and `\meetingNumberLast{1}` in the preamble).

That happens because `\renewcommand` does not evaluate the definition, it just *stores* it.  To force `\getSuperscript` to expand to `st` or `nd` or whatever, you need `\edef` instead of `\renewcommand` (the `e` in `\edef` stands for expanded).  If you change that, `\meetingNumbersconly` and `\lastMeetingNumbersconly` will be `nd` and `st`.

But instead, I suggest you just use the `nth` package (with the option `super` for superscripts):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\begin{document}
  \nth{2} \& \nth{1}
\end{document}
```

or, if you need to set the number prior, then maybe something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super]{nth}

\newcommand\meetingNumberDefault[1]{%
  \getmeetingnumber\meetingNumbersconly{#1}}
\newcommand\meetingNumberLast[1]{%
  \getmeetingnumber\lastMeetingNumbersconly{#1}}

\newcommand\getmeetingnumber[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\nthscript\relax
    \xdef#1{\nth{#2}}%
  \endgroup}

\meetingNumberDefault{2}
\meetingNumberLast{1}

\begin{document}
    \meetingNumbersconly\ \& \lastMeetingNumbersconly
\end{document}
```

Both examples produce:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation with `expl3`. If `\addordinal` is used in a `\write` operation it will output the number in decimal form and the suffix as an argument to `\ORDINAL`, that you can define as you wish (possibly not as a superscript, please).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\addordinal}{m}
 {% #1 should be something that TeX interprets as an integer
  \int_to_arabic:n { #1 }
  \exp_args:Ne \ORDINAL { \deman_compute_suffix:n { #1 } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ORDINAL}{m}{\textsuperscript{#1}}% how ugly is it?

\cs_new:Nn \deman_compute_suffix:n
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {% special cases
    {11}{th}
    {12}{th}
    {13}{th}
   }
   { \__deman_compute_suffix_normal:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__deman_compute_suffix_normal:n
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 10 } }
   {
    {1}{st}
    {2}{nd}
    {3}{rd}
   }
   {th}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addordinal{1}
\addordinal{2}
\addordinal{3}
\addordinal{4}
\addordinal{10}
\addordinal{11}
\addordinal{12}
\addordinal{13}
\addordinal{19}
\addordinal{20}
\addordinal{21}
\addordinal{100}
\addordinal{101}

A ``random'' number \addordinal{\time}

Emulate a write: \edef\writtenout{\addordinal{121}}
\texttt{\meaning\writtenout}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to check for the special cases 11, 12 and 13 first; in the other cases, the suffix is appended based on the last digit, computed with modulo 10 operation.

In the example, the final `\edef` emulates what happens in a `\write` operation.

[image]